# Smoothly slide elements out of the way of a newly appended element using animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm wondering if it's possible to append an element and gently push other elements away from it.

Here is my example [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nomad5/pen/qdLVdv).

```js
/*
var i = 0;
var timerId = setInterval(function(){
  $("ul").append("<li></li> ");
    i++;
    if(i >= 3) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }  
},800);
*/

$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("ul").append("<li></li> ");
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(25, 160, 255, 1);
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px;
  
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform-orgin: center;
  animation-name: popin;
 animation-duration: 0.3s;
 animation-timing-function: easeout;
  
}

li:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


@keyframes popin {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2);
    background: rgba(25, 160, 255, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background: rgba(25, 160, 255, 1);
    animation-timing-function: easeout;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    background: rgba(25, 160, 255, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add More</button>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

You can see that the existing elements are pushed out of the way instantly, is there a way to animate this position change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sure there is](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLqrrL). Normally you'd just need to hide the element when you add it, followed by a delayed showing of it, which JQuery is quite good at doing. Something like this.

```
$n = $("<li></li>").hide();
$("ul").append($n);
$n.show(300); // 300 being the number of milliseconds to take to get to full opacity
```

Well, that's what you'd normally do. However, since you've added a `transition` property to your `li` elements, this overrides JQuery's animation for some obscure reason, stopping the slow adding effect.
The solution to this is fairly simple, create a new CSS class with the attribute

```
transition: intial;
```

and add it to all newly created `li`s so that the add-in effect works, then remove it afterwards to add restore hover functionality.

[Complete CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLqrrL).

Edit: Also another [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXdEew) with a (slightly) better phase-in animation. Putting more effort into the CSS could yield better ones yet, or even using JQueryUI.

Comment: Clever! This is just what I was looking for. I playfully added the hover animation, and I'm glad I did. I had no idea that the transition property overrides jQuery's animation. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice effect but it loses its smoothness when used in interval.. is there a way to preserve the smooth shift of elements in interval ?